# media_handle_upload $post_data how does it work

Tags: php, wordpress

I´m trying to find out how to pass information through $post_data while doing the media handle upload. I can´t find documentation about it.

I have a Form with the Upload, where people fill in the title of the attachment and other custom fields.

Now  i would like to pass this information with the media_handle_upload();

```
<?php media_handle_upload( $file_id, $post_id, $post_data, $overrides ); ?>
```

Can you tell me in which order i have to write in the array?

And am I missing out something else?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can you NOT find documentation? Literally the first result: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload and if that is not enough, check the source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L246

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice comment... Where in the first link there is said something about the values passed in the array??? And for the second, thx, i really didn´t find it.

Comment: Rude comment. Yes there is documentation, but after trying to pass $post_data in, it doesn't work. If you can't say nothing nice, don't say anything. OP has a legit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get into the gritty details, currently $post_data is only used to merge with defaults:

```
$attachment = array_merge( array(
    'post_mime_type' => $type,
    'guid' => $url,
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
), $post_data );
```

Comment: thx, any idea on how to pass beforehand created custom fields? thx in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe add a code sample of the custom field data you want to pass along. If its not one of the default fields, you can use something like `update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_my_custom_attachment_metadata', $data );`. Your previous function returns the attachment id ( on success ).

Comment: thank you! i used update post meta, works like a charm.